# "Subtracting" sets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have $A=\{0,1,2 \}$ and $B=\{0 \}$, then $A-B=\{1,2 \}$ but what is $B-A$?

Comment: Of course, the answer below is correct, but a remark on notation: your "set difference" is often written $A\backslash B$. And, sometimes $A-B$ designs the set of $x-y$ for any $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks, I was actually aware of that but I never bothered to learn how to do \ on latex lol

Comment: @snowman For completeness, it's \setminus.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: For elegantness, try `\smallsetminus`. =)

Comment: @user21820 Ugh, `\setminus` all the way. Can't be doing with these tiny slits of symbols.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Haha.. I find `setminus` to be too long though..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $B-A$ are those elements of $B$ that do not belong to $A$. Do you see any element of $B$ that not in $A$?

$$B-A =\{x| (x\in B) \land (x\notin A) \}= \emptyset$$

Comment: Why is the text a spoiler?

Comment: The answer is in fact $B-A =\emptyset$. the other part is only an informal explanation of answer.